# How to iterate over dictionary in Python whose (k,v) pair uses consecutive items from a list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, range, key

I want to add `(k,v)` pairs to a dictionary `weights` where the key of this dictionary equals an object from a list `layers`. The construction of the value is such that it uses object `l` and object `l+1` from this list. I currently do this as follows:

```
layers = self.layers

for l in range(0, layers.__len__() - 1):
   weights[layers[l]] = np.random.rand(
      layers[l + 1].node_cardinality, 
      layers[l].node_cardinality + 1 
   )
```

Is there a better, shorter way of doing this without having to use the `range()` code?

Comment: Use for k, v in mydict.items() if you are using python 3,or for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if you are using python 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: @Nico238 this isn't a basic items() iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip with the layers and a slice of layers that begins with the second item. Note that `zip()` will stop as soon as any of its iterables are exhausted.

```
for L0, L1 in zip(layers, layers[1:]):
   weights[L0] = np.random.rand(
       L1.node_cardinality, 
       L0.node_cardinality + 1 
   )
```

Depending on what type of sequence `layers` is, it may be more efficient to use an `itertools.islice` instead of a normal slice. A numpy array will probably just use a view if you slice. But a list would have to create a (shallow) copy, so an islice is better if it's very long.

```
for L0, L1 in zip(layers, islice(layers, 1, None)):
   weights[L0] = np.random.rand(
       L1.node_cardinality, 
       L0.node_cardinality + 1 
   )
```

As GrazingScientist has pointed out, this could also be done with a dict comprehension.

```
weights.update(
    {
        L0: np.random.rand(L1.node_cardinality, L0.node_cardinality + 1)
        for L0, L1 in zip(layers, layers[1:])
    }
)
```

But this approach will have to generate a new dict before updating, which may take more memory. The for loop is probably better if `layers` is long. But dicts only contain references, so it's probably not much worse than using a normal list slice is.

It would actually be more efficient to use a generator expression in this case. The `.update()` method can also accept an iterable of `(k, v)` pairs, but a generator doesn't have to allocate them all at once. It just does a pair at a time.

```
weights.update(
    (L0, np.random.rand(L1.node_cardinality, L0.node_cardinality + 1))
    for L0, L1 in zip(layers, islice(layers, 1, None))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). This is more pythonic and probably faster.

```
layers = self.layers
buf_dict = {layers[i]: np.random.rand(layers[i + 1].node_cardinality, layers[i].node_cardinality + 1)
for i, l in zip(layers, layers[1:])}
weights.update(buf_dict)
```

Edit: Forgot code and acknowledged that zip is actually better than enumerate in this case (thanks to gilch), because you won't run into an IndexError.